# Get the master parent node id for a node reference field

Tags: 7, nodes

I have 3 content type "A" , "B", "C".
B has a node reference to A.
C has a node reference to B.

```
B->A
c->B
```

Using simple query I want to get the master parent node Id of C. which is A node id

```
c->B->A
```

How to do this.

Comment: what have you previously tried? are you looking for a DB query for use in a custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a DB query within a custom module, you could do something like the following example function that recursively goes through the reference tree to get to the top for a node.
It will work for N levels, (but not for multi-valued references or nodes with multiple node reference fields).

```
function mymodule_getTopReference($nid){
    $top_nid = 0;
    //load the node
    $node = node_load($nid);
    //get all reference fields
    $node_reference_fields = array();
    $field_infos = field_info_instances('node',$node->type);
    foreach ($field_infos as $field_name=>$value){
        $field = field_info_field($field_name);
        if (($field['type'] == 'node_reference')){
            if ($field_value = field_get_items('node',$node,$field['field_name'])){
                $top_nid = $field_value[0]['nid'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($top_nid && ($parent_nid = mymodule_getTopReference($top_nid))){
        $top_nid = $parent_nid;
    }
    return $top_nid;
}
```

For example, if your node reference field was called "my_reference" and your example nodes had the following nids:

- A = 1
- B = 2
- C = 3

and your references are as you said:

- B->A (2->1)
- C->B (3->2)

Then for node 'C'(3) you'd call this function like so:

```
$top_nid = mymodule_getTopReference(3);
```

which then would set $top_nid to 1 (A's nid).

Comment: yeah I am looking for a query within a custom module. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Its only working for 3 level node reference. Not for 4 level nodereference say D->B->C->A. wanted A. node reference fields are called by different names in every content type. Any idea for this.

Comment: Ahh I did not realize you were dealing with different reference fields across different node types.  I have updated my code accordingly and it should work, I tested with 4 levels.  this is also a more 'drupal' method since we are not doing any direct db querying and are relying on drupals core functions.

Comment: @Mike Miles:Thank you so much. Its Working Perfectly.